# Can not figure out why simple standalone directive in angularjs does not run

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got what I think is about as simple as it gets yet the directive never runs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eKDIWiA1WfK7r5yxMFnN?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <h1>top of app</h1>
  <div my-directive></div>

  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myApp.directive('myDirective ', function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: "<input type='text' ng-model='topData' /> {{ topData }}"
      }
    });
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Where's your controller?

Comment: Do I need one for the app to load?

Comment: Without a controller there is no scope. Without a scope, there is nothing for Angular to work with. I've never seen an example of a directive being used outside of a controller.

Comment: I've updated my plunkr to include a controller but I'm still missing something.  http://plnkr.co/edit/eKDIWiA1WfK7r5yxMFnN?p=preview

Comment: You made a typo. Remove the extra space at the end of the directive name `'myDirective'`.

Comment: Hmm. could not make that work.  I think I have my head on backwards with this one (may need some food).  Here is an example by one of my jetbrains hero's showing directives without a controller.  http://jsfiddle.net/johnlindquist/9Ymvt/1/

Comment: @PeterKellner The fiddle you linked to has a scope in the directive which is why it can get by without a controller. So your original would work if you set a scope for it or just used a blank controller (after fixing the typo, of course).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here that were pointed out in the comments. First, you made a typo with the directive name. Remove the extra space at the end. Second, and more importantly, your directive has no scope. Because of that, `{{topData}}`, or any other binding, won't work because there is no scope for it to exist on. You either need to provide the directive it's own isolated scope or include a controller. I have provided you an example with a controller. [JsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/gafaluvoju/1/edit?html,output).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController">
  <h1>top of app</h1>
  <div my-directive></div>

  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myapp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.topData = 'Hello';
    });

    myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="topData" /> {{ topData }}'
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```